# C++ How Many Page-Faults are Created with COW?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, memory-management, malloc

I have seen this question online, and am not sure if my answer is correct or not:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define N 100*1024*1024
int a[N];

int main() {
    if (fork() > 0) {
        wait(nullptr);
    } else {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            a[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The question was:

> Considering COW technique is enabled in x86-64 OS (With a page size of 4KB = 4096B) how many page faults the child process creates during its whole runtime. (Not looking for very exact answer)
>
> 1. 1024*1
> 2. 1024*10
> 3. 1024*100
> 4. 1024*1024
> 5. 1024*1024*10
> 6. 1024*1024*100

I think the correct one is 6 since we will try to copy `N` elements each time the child process tries to write to a write-protected location in memory. Am I right?

I tried to run `strace` with my program, and it seems none are correct, as the output didn't contain any thousands of lines representing each page fault:

```
strace ./a.out
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7ffd84f9ace0 /* 50 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55c515202000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=96020, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 96020, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f93cbf68000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\35\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f93cbf66000
mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f93cb966000
mprotect(0x7f93cbb4d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f93cbd4d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f93cbd4d000
mmap(0x7f93cbd53000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f93cbd53000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f93cbf674c0) = 0
mprotect(0x7f93cbd4d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55c4fb12b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f93cbf80000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f93cbf68000, 96020)           = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f93cbf67790) = 3341
wait4(-1, NULL, 0, NULL)                = 3341
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3341, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=19, si_stime=35} ---
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: I am only seeing 4 `mprotect`

Comment: Can we see the assembly generated? Sometimes, our compilers are [smarter than expected](https://godbolt.org/z/aoPEs7nGd).

Comment: @YSC Hi, I am more interested in the theoretical answer, my try was just to see if it will help me verify my answer. I can still provide the assembly code but I don't think it's need for the theoretical side. Thanks for telling me that the compiler can do different things.

Comment: One.  It's a really big page.  Oh, wait.  The question never specified the page size (or much of anything else...) and is therefore completely unanswerable...

Comment: n/m  I was wrong.  It is 1024 * 25 * sizeof(int) pages.  For 4-byte ints, that is 1024*100.

Comment: where sizeof(int) came from? The provided answer claims it's 1024 * 25 may you provide yours and help me and others as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page faults don't show up in strace; they are not even something that happens "explicitly".

A page fault happens every time a piece of memory is accessed for which the assigned physical page is either not created yet, or mapped into the address space.

In practice the number of page faults for your program is sizeof(int)*N/pagesize. Explanation:

The array `a` is created in the global `.data` segment, but default initialized. `.data` is mapped MAP_ANONYMOUS once, at process start, and by virtue of population-initialization it's zeroing will happen on the first page fault. Since the parent process never accesses the array `a`, no single page fault for the address space occupied by `a` will happen in the parent process.

The only process that will cause page faults on `a` is the child process. However a page fault happens only for the first access of a previously non-resident page. Since `a` is traversed sequentially the pagefaults on `a` will only happen on those accessed where `0 == ((uintptr_t)&a[i]) % pagesize` (assuming uintptr_t cast pointers correspond exactly to addresses, which on most platforms, they do).

Of course in a system with high memory pressure the system might thrash, thus swapping out the page, before the iterator reached the next page, thus creating additional page faults.

Comment: So 2 and 3 are correct according to what you explained, but the correct is only one answer.

Comment: Hi, a comment suggested the answer is 1024 * 25 * sizeof(int) pages while yours claim it's 1024 * 25 can you explain this contradiction?

Comment: @daniel: `sizeof(a) = sizeof(int) * N`. On Linux `sizeof(int) == 4` and (at the date writing this) `pagesize == 4 * 1024`. Thus the approximate number of pagefaults is `sizeof(a) / pagesize == 4*100*1024*1024 / (4*1024) == 100*1024` → answer 3